# How to use properly numpy.loadtxt to separate data correctly?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this piece of code that works:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
file_path = sys.argv[1]
training_examples = np.loadtxt(file_path)
print(training_examples)
```

and the output a text containing sequences of 1/0 separated by spaces and new lines:

```
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

What I want to achieve is an easy separation of this data to a matrix and a vector, while the vector would be built of the last values like this:

```
[1. 1. 1.]
```

and the corresponding matrix for that vector would be:

```
[[ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the content of that file of yours?

Comment: as the output just separated with one space between each number and newlines between each sequence like this.

Comment: How is `matrix = np.loadtxt(file_path, usecols=(0,1,2)); vector = np.loadtxt(file_path, usecols=(3,))`? This assumes that you have 4 columns, of course.

Comment: That is exactly what I was needed, thank you very much!

Comment: another question what if the amount of columns is not known? the only thing that is, is that the last value in the sequence belongs to the vector...

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `usecols` parameter from the `loadtxt` function, if you happen to know the number of columns in your file:

```
# Assuming you have 4 columns
matrix = np.loadtxt(file_path, usecols=(0,1,2))
vector = np.loadtxt(file_path, usecols=(3,))
```

But if you do not know the number of columns, you can try importing the whole file and then slicing the data into a matrix and a vector:

```
# Get the whole file
data = np.loadtxt(file_path)

# Get the number of columns in the data
col_num = data.shape[1]

# Get the matrix
matrix = data[:,:(col_num-1)]

# Get the vector
vector = data[:,col_num-1]
```

I hope this helps.